# Laravel - cURL error 28 (timeout) when running queue work

Tags: laravel, curl

I need to synchronize a local database with data from an external API.
This synchronization is time-consuming and is done in a queued job.
I query around 15,000 records, and the API only returns 100 records per page, so I need to make several queries to retrieve them all.
The problem is that it starts making requests, but at some point it returns an error `cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10001 milliseconds`.
When running the task on my local computer, it works normally, but when running it on the hosting server it generates this error.
Searching around I saw that it could be a memory limit on the server. If so, how would you free up memory while the queued job runs?
Another thing, to test I set a `timeout` ofI need to synchronize a local database with data from an external API.
This synchronization is time-consuming and is done in a queued job.
I query around 15,000 records, and the API only returns 100 records per page, so I need to make several queries to retrieve them all.
The problem is that it starts making requests, but at some point it returns an error `cURL error 28: Resolving timed out after 10001 milliseconds`.
When running the task on my local computer, it works normally, but when running it on the hosting server it generates this error.
Searching around I saw that it could be a memory limit on the server. If so, how would you free up memory while the queued job runs?
Another thing, to test I set a `timeout` of 30 seconds, but the error returns a `timeout` of 10 seconds.
I'm using Laravel's Http Client for requests. 30 seconds, but the error returns a `timeout` of 10 seconds.